# logout confirmation message is not working laravel-8

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-8

I laravel I am trying to create a logout confirmation message when I click on my logout button
for this I have done this to my navebar.blade.php

```
<a class="dropdown-item" id="logout" href="{{ route('admin.logout') }}">
{{ __('Logout') }}
</a>
```

and this to my admin.blade.php but not working but it should work

```
<script>
        $(docoment).on("click", "#logout", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var link = $(this).attr("href");
            swal({
                    title: "Are you Want to logout?",
                    text: "",
                    icon: "warning",
                    buttons: true,
                    dragerMode: true,
                })
                .then((willDelete) => {
                    if (willDelete) {
                        window.location.href = link;
                    } else {
                        swal("Not Logout");
                    }
                });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here the `<a>` tag doesn't waits for the click function to execute. It will redirects to the link in href. So change the function as follows.

```
<a class="dropdown-item" id="logout" data-link="{{ route('admin.logout') }}">
    {{ __('Logout') }}
</a>
<script>
    $(docoment).on("click", "#logout", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var link = $(this).attr("data-link");
        swal({
                title: "Are you Want to logout?",
                text: "",
                icon: "warning",
                buttons: true,
                dragerMode: true,
            })
            .then((willDelete) => {
                if (willDelete) {
                    window.location.href = link;
                } else {
                    swal("Not Logout");
                }
            });
    });
</script>
```

If you are using  jQuery >= 1.4.3, then you can also get the data attribute like

```
var link = $(this).data("link");
```

Comment: Thank you. But now it's still not working and also not logouting

Comment: Is the click function executing ?

Comment: without script code, I can logout but when I use script code and use id name in my button its not working

Comment: Is there any error in console ?

Comment: no its not showing any error

Comment: can you place an alert on the click function and check it is executing ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242099/discussion-between-amal-s-r-and-shahed-khan).

Answer (score 0):

Well I'd prefer to create a form to logout. Get method for logging out is not recommended.

```
<form action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="post" id="logoutorm">
  @csrf
   <button type="submit" class="dropdown-item">
      <i class="far fa-fw fa-arrow-alt-circle-left mr-1"></i> {{ __('Sign Out') }}
   </button>
 </form>
```

To submit this form via sweet alert you can do something like this:

```
<script>
$(document).on("submit", "#logoutorm", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let form = $(this);
    swal({
            title: "Are you Want to logout?",
            text: "",
            icon: "warning",
            buttons: true,
            dragerMode: true,
        })
        .then((willDelete) => {
            if (willDelete) {
                form.submit();
            } else {
                swal("Logout Canceled");
            }
        });
});
```

Hope this would work for you :)

Comment: its logging out but alert message are not showing

Comment: Than your js code is not working. It should prevent form from submitting.